# Error regarding excel reading in python3 using xlrd in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlrd, errno

```
import xlrd

loc = ('‪E:\python\project2 new companies\branchpin.xlsx')   
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
for i in range(sheet.nrows-1):                #going through excel
    data = sheet.cell_value(i+1,4)
    print(data)
```

error is :[Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aE:\python\project2 new companies\x08ranchpin.xlsx'

Comment: You need to either escape your slashes or make the file path a raw string. `loc = ('‪E:\\python\\project2 new companies\\branchpin.xlsx')` or `loc = (r'‪E:\python\project2 new companies\branchpin.xlsx')`

Comment: just use raw string, python is adding a non-printing character ("\u202a"). so just use `loc = r'‪E:\python\project2 new companies\branchpin.xlsx'`

Comment: have tried both the methods , i am still getting the same issue .